# Averages of side and averages of angles in a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

I came across the following exercise

> If a side of a triangle is less than the Averages  of the two others sides, then the opposite angle  is less than the average of the  two other angles.

Can anyone help me to prove this statement

I failed to apply Alkashi theorem here.

Comment: Try the law of sines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple by drawing the involved loci:

[image]

The first constraint ensures that $A$ lies outside the depicted ellipse, hence it also lies outside the depicted circles. In algebraic terms, $a<\frac{b+c}{2}$ implies
$$\cos(A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}>\frac{1}{2}$$
hence $A>60^\circ$ and $A>\frac{B+C}{2}=90^\circ-\frac{A}{2}$.

Comment: Very nice answer! (+1)